# MudAutocomplete - need Bind value on edit form

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am using MudAutocomplete control on my form. Now, when the user clicks the edit icon on a grid, I am showing a popup screen with a form pre-filling the selected record data. Now, all other controls are pre-filling with binded values but for MudAutocomplete control, it's not happening. Please help me here how can I achieve this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple snippet showing how to load a value into autocomplete. You can play around with the snippet at https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOcFbFbUhRRLfdsj

```html
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6">
        <MudButton OnClick="LoadFormData">
            Load Form Data
        </MudButton>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <MudAutocomplete T="string" Label="US States" @bind-Value="_value" 
                SearchFunc="@Search1" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>

@code {
   
    string _value = null;

    private void LoadFormData()
    {
        _value="New Mexico";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private string[] states =
    {
        "Alabama", "Alaska", "American Samoa", "Arizona",
        "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut",
        "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Federated States of Micronesia",
        "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Idaho",
        "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky",
        "Louisiana", "Maine", "Marshall Islands", "Maryland",
        "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi",
        "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada",
        "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York",
        "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Ohio",
        "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Palau", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico",
        "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee",
        "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virgin Island", "Virginia",
        "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming",
    };

    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Search1(string value)
    {
        // In real life use an asynchronous function for fetching data from an api.
        await Task.Delay(5);

        // if text is null or empty, show complete list
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return states;
        return states.Where(x => x.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

When you click "Load Form Data" the autocomplete is pre-filled with the value. If this doesn't solve your problem you need to create an http://try.mudblazor.com snippet and post it here, so we can take a look at your problem. Just make sure you keep it simple.